# Paypal integration for android deprecated

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

When I tried to find official documentation for android for integrating paypal express, I found

> Important: PayPal Mobile SDKs are now Deprecated and only existing integrations are supported. For all new integrations, use Braintree Direct or Express Checkout'.

I couldn't find any android documentation in the recommended pages as well. Is it something like we have to use the REST API provided by them in android as well?

Please guide me how I can implement paypal in android.

Comment: Searching "BrainTree Direct" leads me here, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/bt-direct-overview/ And from there, you go to "setup your client", and there is a drop down in the middle of the page with Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the Braintree SDK?  It will tie PayPal, direct credit card processing, Venmo, Apple and Google Pay in a single integration.  That's what I would recommend.

Specifically, you should use their Drop In UI.  Here's a guide for [Android integration with Braintree](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/android/v2).

Comment: What about unsupported countries, what should we use? Is it possible to use paypal without Braintree?

Comment: @Drew Angell 
What about unsupported countries, what should we use? Is it possible to use paypal without Braintree?